# Angular 4 Observable service not working for an api http get

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-observable

Angular 4 Observable service not working for an api http get.

The http that returns an observable doesnt seem to work.

I'm using the new HttpClient

**This is the error I get:**

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

**Solution?**

> It doesn't seem to like Observable going to the ngFor. Maybe I need to
>   do a switchMap? in the component.

**This is my http service call:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';

import { User } from "../models/user.model";

@Injectable()

export class UserService {
    private baseUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {        
        return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseUrl)
          .retry(2)
          .catch(e => this.handleError("Get Users Error", e));
    }

    private handleError(errorMessage: string, error: Object): any {
      console.log(errorMessage, error);
    }
};
```

**This is my html:**

```
<div class="column" *ngFor="let user of listOfUsers | async; let i = index">
    <p>{{i + 1}}.{{user.name}}</p>
</div>
```

**This is my component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { UserService } from "../../services/user.service";
import { User } from "../../models/user.model";

@Component({
  selector: "home-users",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private listOfUsers: Observable<User[]>;
  loading: boolean;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.listOfUsers = this.userService.getUsers().do(_ => this.loading = false);
  }
}
```

**This is my model:**

```
export class User {
  name: string;
};
```

Comment: If you use angualr 4.3 then use following tutorial https://angular.io/guide/http since HttpClient does not need a map and json.

Answer (score 2):

Surely if you change your Home Component to the following it will resolve you issue?

```
getUsers(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
            // --> Observable<T> returns here
            this.listOfUsers = users; // or if json: this.listOfUsers = users.json();
        },
        (errors) => {
            // --> Errors are returned here
        },
        () => {
            // --> always called when finished
            this.loading = false;
        });
}
```

*edit*

You'll have to map the returned data for async:

```
this.listOfUsers = this.userService.getUsers().map((data)=> return data.json() || []);
```

this.works fine on my side, check out this article: [angular-2-async-pipe-example](http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-async-pipe-example)

Comment: Yeah that worked but I want to use | async in my ngFor and therefore not have to subscribe

Comment: I get this error when I do that with an | async: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: I can't replicate that issue, [https://plnkr.co/edit/dbdhg0mZVeCNGm6izlVT?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/dbdhg0mZVeCNGm6izlVT?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following changes:

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
};

@Injectable()

export class UserService {
    private baseUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseUrl)
      .retry(2)
      .catch(e => this.handleError("Get Users Error", e));
}

private handleError(errorMessage: string, error: HttpErrorResponse | any){
  console.log(errorMessage, error);
}
```

}

The new `HttpClient` doesnt define a `Response` class with a json method. Instead of that now developers can use the HTTP methods with a type parameter.

This is the screen shot of my console error:

[image]

Comment: Ok I've added your service changes above. I now get this error: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like Observable going to the ngFor. Maybe I need to do a switchMap? in the component. If so How I do that for the component?

Comment: I get the same error: I think its because my component receives this: Observable<Observable<Users[]>> when it needs possibly a switchMap to Observable<Users[]> but I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: your component should receive Observable<User[]> as defined in the interface of the service. Maybe your endpoint address is not returning an array

Comment: in the component remove the private modifier from listOfUsers

Comment: I still get the same error when removing private from listOfUsers. I've added a screen shot of the error and also printed the console log for the service response

Comment: remove the catch in the service method, or return something from handleError

Comment: I've tried this: return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseUrl); and it still gives me the same error. The ngFor doesnt like the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153770/discussion-between-jota-toledo-and-angularm).