# Angular 5 Typescript says webpack failed as Property data does not exists on type Response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular-httpclient

I seem to get an error with webpack compiling.  It compiles if I remove `.data` but then the page blows up with the calls from template->component (which calls a service

Error I am getting

> ERROR in src/app/components/app-landing-page/app-landing-page.component.ts(95,41): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response'.

```
 webpack:  Failed to compile
```

That is when my component has

```
this.referrals = result.data;
```

component:

```
this.arsSevice.getArsCodesApi(this.model)
    .subscribe(
        result => {

            this.referrals = result.data;
            console.log('component',result);
        })
```

**Service:**

```
getArsCodesApi(search: arsCodes) {
    return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(search), httpOptions)
    JSON.stringify(search), options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response;              
        })
  }
```

**FYI   http is the new  httpclient**

Once I compile it without .data  -- running with `ng serve --open`  then i have to add .data back in

If I don't add it, the call fails to work and i get this error

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

**WHY???** ( console.log  clearly shows that that is data : Array(16)  )

**Edit Update**   showing console.log of data

[image: screenshot of console.log data array]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Observable service not working for an api http get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072281/angular-4-observable-service-not-working-for-an-api-http-get)

Comment: @Al-Mothafar the linked question has two contradictory answers, neither accepted, and both of low quality.

Comment: Why do you have code like `.map((response: Response) => {return response;})`? The type annotation can mask an error (remove it). The function does nothing except (possibly) change the static type of the observable. Also, components should not unwrap result properties like that, the service should handle it.

Comment: can you add what console.log('component',result); shows? you are probably trying to Iterate the object inside the array.

Comment: @RildoGomez    question updated  showing the image of the console.log   thx

Comment: @AluanHaddad   i'm rather new to arrow functions,   remove the "type annotation "  means to remove exactly which part?   thx

Comment: @ScottLeary go from `(response: Response) => {}` to `response => {}`

Comment: @ScottLeary which error do you you need help with? `TS2339` or `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` I can't even tell from reading your question what state your code is in. Also you have a weird random stringify call between return and map and a bunch of other stuff. Please explain more clearly.

Comment: without the : Response  , I cannot get the page to display any records on the page with and without  .data on the end of the result

Comment: JSON.stringify(search)  is for  the typescript class   getArsCodesApi(search: arsCodes)

Comment: @ScottLeary type annotations do not change the shape of the data at all. So it's not possible that removing one would change the data that is displayed. Also I still have no idea what your service method is trying to do because it doesn't make any sense the way it's written

Comment: @AluanHaddad  -  well this is the 2nd job that I have been on teams in which i have written the http.post this way.   Could you please provide an answer showing me a better way of doing this from a component and service ?

Comment: @ScottLeary can't you just `return this.http.post(whatever);`? Again, if you look at the service method you posted here, it doesn't make sense because you have a random call to stringify in the middle of it and your mapping it with an identity function.

Comment: you should be using `.subscribe((data) => { // do something // })` as the new `HttpClient` returns an `Observable<Object>`. Also possible duplicate of your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642788/angular-5-getting-array-issue-with-data-from-service-to-component-to-template/47643928#47643928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like Nicholas Pesa commented, the `HttpClient` parses your response in an Object, and it does not know what shape it is. So either use bracket notation or then type your data (recommended):

```
export interface MyResponse {
  data: MyType[];
}

export interface MyType {
  ID: number;
  ARSCode: string;
  // rest of properties
}
```

Then explicitly tell Angular that you are receiving a response of type `MyResponse`, also as a bonus you can tell Angular what type of data you are expecting, i.e an observable array of `MyType`:

```
getArsCodesApi(search: arsCodes): Observable<MyType[]> {
  return this.http.post<MyResponse>(this.serviceUrl, search, httpOptions)
    .map(res => res.data)
}
```

Then in your component you just subscribe to it.

```
referrals: MyType[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.arsSevice.getArsCodesApi(this.model)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.referrals = result;
        console.log('component',result);
    })
}
```

Read more about typechecking with the `HttpClient` from the docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response